# How can I set Background Color for a Scene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have put

```
super.viewDidLoad()
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

in

```
override func viewDidLoad() { 

}
```

of GameViewController.swift. But the background doesn't change to yellow. Then, I even add that code to:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

}
```

But still, the background doesn't change.

Any way can I change the color of my scene's background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the background color of the **scene** not background color of your view controller's view:

```swift
// let's create a test Scene

public func setupScene() -> SKScene {
    let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768))
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFit    // define the scaleMode for this scene
    scene.backgroundColor = SKColor.lightGrayColor()   // HERE: background color

    return scene
}
```

**EDIT**: To set a "background image", you just add a SKSpriteNode to the scene

```swift
// let's create a test Scene

public func setupScene() -> SKScene {
    let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768))
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFit    // define the scaleMode for this scene

    let n = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background.png")
    scene.addChild(n)
    return scene
}
```

Comment: if I want my App to run properly in all iOS devices, can i still use the specific width and height values : (width: 1024, height: 768)

Comment: No, that was just an example. Pick your viewcontroller's width & height from frame or bounds properties

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I know that it is a bit off topic, but if I want to set a background image, what code should I use?

Comment: Updated. I recommend you to learn the basics of SpriteKit, following a simple tutorial like [this one](https://www.raywenderlich.com/119815/sprite-kit-swift-2-tutorial-for-beginners). Also, remember to mark as resolved your question (if it's resolved)

Comment: @DiegoFreniche I got the same problem and knew the scene background color can be set, but I want to load gameScene only after the start button is clicked. So I need to set the gameViewController background color first, but it always keep gray ;-(. Can't the view background color be changed under spritKite?

Comment: I think it's better to post a new question (as yours is complex) and link here

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the color of scene and not your ViewController

I change my background to red

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

backgroundColor = SKColor.redColor()

}
```